# Spring Cloud Contract Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-contract

I am trying to do the Spring Cloud Contract integration in our existing project. I have got the stub verifier working. But when i am trying use that stub in client, I am getting the following exception. I am trying to get this working offline. Please let me know if you need any more details on the same.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-07-10 15:26:42.330 ERROR 20476 [] --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'stubFlowRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/contract/stubrunner/messaging/integration/StubRunnerIntegrationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'stubFlowRegistrar' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchStubRunner' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/contract/stubrunner/spring/StubRunnerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner]: Factory method 'batchStubRunner' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchStubRunner' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/contract/stubrunner/spring/StubRunnerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner]: Factory method 'batchStubRunner' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner]: Factory method 'batchStubRunner' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.AetherFactories.newSession(AetherFactories.java:63)
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.AetherStubDownloader.<init>(AetherStubDownloader.java:83)
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubDownloaderBuilderProvider.getOrDefaultDownloader(StubDownloaderBuilderProvider.java:48)
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration.batchStubRunner(StubRunnerConfiguration.java:75)
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$52aa72bb.CGLIB$batchStubRunner$0(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$52aa72bb$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$35176646.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$52aa72bb.batchStubRunner(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 61 common frames omitted
2017-07-10 15:26:42.332 ERROR 20476 [] --- [main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener
```

Comment: Which version of sc-contract are you using? Can you provide your simple project somewhere? If I was to guess there's a mismatch between Aether versions. Could you please try to use latest snapshots and see if the problem persists? In 1.2.x (Edgware.BUILD-SNAPSHOT release train) we've invested some time to repackage Aether. Maybe that would help?

Comment: Currently i am using org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner:1.1.1.RELEASE.

Comment: Are using a release train? Which one is it? Can you check the 1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (which comes from Edgware.BUILD-SNAPSHOT release train) ?

Comment: Thanks Marcin for Quick Reply, that version worked for me. Getting some other issue though, will try to debug that one now :)

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the info. I'll create an answer in a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the problem was related to Aether version mismatch. It's enough to bump version to Edgware release train where we've managed to shade Aether and finally Stub Runner is independent on the used Aether version.